# How can I generate doxygen documentation of opencv3.0 from its code

Tags: opencv, doxygen, opencv3.0

I have the source code of **opencv3.0** and I want to use **doxygen** to generate **HTML documentation** for it (I know that the online documentation is available, I want generate it myself). But when I run doxygen on main folder of opencv I get nothing(just one page).

Where the documentation comments of opencv are written?

Are the documentation inside the code or they are written separately?

Comment: Hi @Ali Mirzaei. How's everything going?  Do you generate the doc successfully?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this can help you. I followed this instruction and got the offline document succcessfully.

http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/db1/tutorial_documentation.html#gsc.tab=0

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I finally figured it out

### Let's talk about Doxygen

Doxygen can read the comments of code and generate into html format with functions,

and if you want to visualize the function call, doxygen combines `graphviz` for you already

#### Doxygen GUI - Doxywizard

I prefer using Doxygen GUI (it's name is `doxywizard`), because it's more *intuitive* and *instructive*.

If your OS is Ubuntu 16.04, the installation is simple:

```
Sudo apt-get install doxygen-gui
```

The best thing is, every choice in expert dialog can show its description (that's why I say instructive)

Just in case you don't use something you don't want.

**Doxywizard documentation**

- [Doxywizard usage](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/doxywizard_usage.html)
- [Short Tutorial YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-V_vHZPOZfY)

### Personal Opinion

In my personal perspective, the OpenCV official documentation list everything

**But the detail of what I want**

Such as the source code of certain function, ex. `UMat`, the OpenCL supported version of `Mat`

That's a little bit pitty.